# What is the difference if I use "withContext(Dispatchers.IO)" or not?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

### Hi, I am a beginner in coroutines but I have some problems ...

I have two different codes, the first use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` , and the second doesn't use it.

1. what is the difference between these two codes?
2. why are they have the same result?
3. How does every code work line by line?
4. Tips to learn everything in coroutines.

---

- the first code

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            print("aly")
            print("younes")
        }
    }

    suspend fun print(name:String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(2000)
            Log.d("younes3", name)
        }
    }

}
```

---

- the second code

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            print("aly")
            print("younes")
        }
    }

    suspend fun print(name:String) {
        delay(2000)
        Log.d("younes3", name)
    }
}
```

- the first code

> 2022-11-13 10:28:02.122 21136-21176 younes3                 com.example.coroutines1              D  aly
>
> 2022-11-13 10:28:04.124 21136-21178 younes3                 com.example.coroutines1              D  younes

- the second code

> 2022-11-13 10:28:26.511 21286-21326 younes3                 com.example.coroutines1              D  aly
>
> 2022-11-13 10:28:28.512 21286-21328 younes3                 com.example.coroutines1              D  younes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty unfocused, so I'll focus on what `Dispatchers.IO` does and why your code works exactly the same with or without it.

As a general rule, we should not perform any blocking I/O operations when using coroutines. That means reading/writing files or network while using utilities like e.g. `InputStream` which is blocking. Blocking inside coroutines may greatly degrade the performance and responsiveness of the whole application using coroutines.

However, it would be very hard to never perform any blocking I/O. For this reason, Kotlin coroutines framework provided an utility that allows blocking I/O by executing it inside a very special context - this is `Dispatchers.IO`. Internally, it schedules the blocking operation to a special thread pool which was designed specifically for this purpose.

You don't see any difference between both code samples, because `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` already run its code using `Dispatchers.IO`. `print()` is invoked using `Dispatchers.IO` already, so additional `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` doesn't do anything.

I suggest switching to `Dispatchers.IO` only in the code that handles blocking I/O directly. We generally should not switch to this dispatcher if our code only invokes other suspending functions, even if these functions are somehow related to I/O operations. For this reason, you should not use `Dispatchers.IO` in `GlobalScope.launch()`.

Additionally, `print()` function in your code also doesn't do any blocking I/O, so as a matter of fact, you should remove `withContext()` as well. If that was just an example and you are going to perform blocking I/O inside `print()`, then you should use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` there, but still not in `onCreate()`.